How Can I Eliminate The Time From The Date
First of all I'm using an API where the date returns to me as a String and it returns to me in format of yyyy-MM-dd so what I want to get is 4 September 2024 and I managed to do it but I can't eliminate the time out of the date.
My DateFormatter code is;
var newDate:DateFormatter {
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd.MM.yy"
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none
    
    return dateFormatter
}

and what it gives me is this

also when I'm Parsing the JSON I use;
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601

So what am I doing wrong guys ?
and this is how I use it on my code;
Text("Release Date: \(newDate.date(from: part.releaseDate) ?? Date.now)")


What's part.releaseDate?

the date that comes from the API

Do you want the date format to always be “4 September 2024” or do you want to show that format in, for example, the UK, but then to show “September 4, 2024” in the US? We generally want to localize date formats in accordance with the device settings, e.g. dateStyle of .long, and timeStyle of none, and do not set the dateFormat). The key is to use that formatter when performing the string interpolation of the dates in Text, e.g., Text("Release Date: \(date, formatter: formatter)").

You are using the date formatter incorrectly. date(from:) makes a date, whereas what you want is a string.

what I want to get is 4 September 2024

Your code, though pretty incorrect of itself, works correctly if you change date(from:) to string(from:) and fix the formatter, if the input is a Date:
var newDate:DateFormatter {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM yyyy"
    return dateFormatter
}

print("Release Date: \(newDate.string(from: Date.now))")

Result:
Release Date: 4 September 2024

It may be that you need two formatters, one to turn what comes from the API into a Date and the other (this one) to turn that Date into a string for presentation. But you have not shown enough code for me to know that.

Note that this use of a computed property to generate the date formatter is incorrect, as you will get a new date formatter instance every time the formatter is referred to. Date formatters are expensive. What you want here is a static property that is initialized only once.

I needed two formatters, thank you so much.

Yes, the dateDecodingStrategy is used to convert the string in JSON to a Date object, and then a formatter used in the Text string interpolation to format the Date into a format for the UI. But do not use a computed property for the date formatter. Use a static initialized by a closure, not a computed property. The former initializes it once with a closure, and the latter with go through the expensive process of creating a new formatter every time you reference that computed property.
